# como ejecutar tabla temporal Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Por que no puedo hacer consulta a la tabla temporal, aun cuando la consulta dinamica ejecuta correctamente..?

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * into #User from [dbo].[Usuario]'
exec (@sql)

select * from #User
```

¿hay alguna manera de hacer esto ?

Comment: Qué resultado obtienes al ejecutar esas sentencias que pones en tu pregunta?

Comment: ¿Seguro que es MySQL?

Comment: es SQL, la respuesta que obtengo, despues del exec(@sql) es : (8 rows affected) pero cuando hago la consulta a la tabla temporal sale:  Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 8
El nombre de objeto '#User' no es válido.

Comment: El código es claramente Transact-SQL, que es el lenguaje de SQL Server, que es el producto de Microsoft. MySQL es otro producto. SQL es el estándar sobre el cual se basan los productos.

Comment: Existe una forma de hacer eso, pero el código que muestras no requiere que sea dinámico. ¿Qué es lo que intentas hacer? Las tablas temporales locales se destruyen cuando la sesión termina. En este caso, la sesión que crea la tabla termina cuando termina la ejecución del código dinámico.

Comment: el punto es que ira dentro de un procedimiento que recibe el nombre de bd.tabla que esta enlazado con Linked Servers, debajo tengo una consulta inmensa  entonces lo que necesito es que simplemente cambie la bd.tabla pasando a una tabla temporal que sera usada en otra consulta... sino hago eso tendria que crear otro procedimientos...o duplicar la consulta con la que trabaja la tabla temporal, no se si me dejo entender D:

Comment: cuando ejecutas código con SQL dinámico, el scope de esa ejecución es válida solo dentro de ese mismo código. Por eso si creas la tabla temporal dentro de esa ejecución, una vez fuera ya será eliminada

Answer (score 2):

Si puedes anticipar la estructura de la tabla, puedes crear primero la tabla temporal, ejecutar tu sentencia y obtener los resultados, por ejemplo:

```
create table #temporal (campo1 int, campo2 varchar(100));
set @sql = 'insert into #tepmoral select campo1, campo2 from tabla';
exec @sql;

select * from #temporal
```

Si no puedes anticiparlo, como ya has descubierto, no puedes usar un `select into #temporal` ya que el ámbito en el que se ejecuta el SQL dinámico es distinto al de tu rutina y, por tanto, la tabla temporal que se crea en ese ámbito no es visible desde el punto donde se llama.

Un *truco* que puedes aplicar es valerte de una tabla temporal global. Estas tablas comienzan con `##` y son visibles para todas las sesiones dentro del servidor. Por tanto, este código no puede ejecutarse en varias sesiones en paralelo. Suponiendo que la concurrencia de tu sistema no es tan alta en el punto donde utilices este truco, puede salvarte el dia.

La idea es crear una tabla global temporal *al vuelo*, para inmediatamente trasladar los datos a una tabla temporal normal, por ejemplo:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = 'select * into ##temporal from MiTabla';

if object_id('tempdb..#temporal', 'U') is not null drop table #temporal;
if object_id('tempdb..##temporal', 'U') is not null drop table ##temporal;

exec (@sql)

--acá trasladamos los datos a una tabla temporal normal, para que otras sesiones puedan tirar del mismo mecanismo.
select * into #temporal from ##temporal;

select * from #temporal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción válida, es definir la estructura de la tabla temporal fuera del código dinámico, de manera que la sentencia es un Insert into #user....

```
Create table Usuario (id int , nombre varchar(10))
go
Insert into dbo.Usuario(id, nombre)
values
(1,'a'),
(2,'b');
go
```

Con la tabla real, puedes aplicar:

```
Create table #User (id int, texto varchar(10));
Declare @sql nvarchar(max);
Set @sql = N'Insert into #User (id, texto)
            Select * from dbo.Usuario;
            ';

exec sp_executeSql @sql;

Select * from #User;
```

[image: Resultado]